# Screen Personas - reorder elements after disappearing elements

Tags: screen, abap, dynpro

I'm pretty new to screen personas.
I built a module pool dynpro screen and now want to adjust the screen elements.

On my first screen there are several input elements and labels, whose visibility can be changed by clicking a button.

When I start my program and click the button to set the visibility of the inputfields und labels, the other elements (below the elements, which are disappearing) adjust their position and move upwards to fill the gap.

After clicking the button again, the fields will be visible again and the elements below move downwards.

Now the problem is in screen personas: I changed the positions and sizes of the buttons, labels and input fields. When I now click the button to change the visibility, the elements just disappear and the elements below stay at their position, instead of moving upwards to fill the gap. Is it possible to define a layout or something, that the elements fill the gap, the invisible elements left behind?

I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: At the Screen Attributes there is a checkbox: "Switch Off Screen Compress" Please check first if it is NOT ticked (however it is not ticked by default) - if it ids ticked, than remove it and test the screen again. Reading the F1 Help for this field, might also answer, why the screen is not compressed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
Apparently it's switched off. Also the program deletes the empty space, when the elements are invisible, so that is correct. But I want to do the same after styling it in screen personas. Is this possible? 
Thanks!